# Unhiding a hidden tab bar (tabbar)

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a tab bar style application and once the user navigates into the application (selecting a tab bar), the tab bar is hidden using         `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true` in a `viewDidLoad` function

How can I reshow the tab bar later.  I've tried         `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false` in both `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: When is "later"?  And what are the results of what you're currently trying?  How many view controllers are we talking about?  This is a ["Does Not Work"](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) question.

Comment: Add more code. the description is a bit vague. Are you trying to show it again when you push another vc?

Comment: @ nhgrif : I try to reshow the tab bar 8 view controllers later

Comment: @Ron Yes I am trying to show the tab bar after i push many view controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a setting in the storyboard of the view controller that is going on the navigation stack:

[image: Storyboard settings]

if you check [x] Hide Bottom Bar on Push, the tab bar will be hidden when a view controller is pushed onto the navigation stack. It will also be unhidden when that view controller is removed (popped).